# Trying to understand function closure, lexical environement in this example. declared with let variables vs object properties

Tags: javascript, html, object, web, scope

Going through some lessons about lexical environment, closure, and that function are objects. But, the following code, I can't understand how counter.count can accumulate, even when it gets reset back to 0 every call at `counter.count = 0`

> Function properties can replace closures sometimes. For instance, we
>   can rewrite the counter function example from the chapter Variable
>   scope to use a function property:

Excerpt from Javascript.info

```js
function makeCounter() {
  // instead of:
  // let count = 0

  function counter() {
    return counter.count++;
  };

  counter.count = 0;

  return counter;
}

let counter = makeCounter();
alert( counter() ); // 0
alert( counter() ); // 1
```

even in this example without using properties

```js
function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;

  return function() {
    return count++;
  };
}

let counter = makeCounter();
alert( counter()); //0
alert( counter()); //1
```

does `let`  declare count once during function declaration? Subsequent repeated calls in `counter()` wouldn't trigger `let counter = 0;` again?

wouldn't repeated calls be equalvent like the follow code? b/c I know this will give an error

```js
let counter = 0;
let counter = 0;
```

code excerpt from Javascript.info

Comment: _"wouldn't trigger let counter = 0; again?"_ - No. `makeCounter` returns `function counter() { ... }`. And `counter()` only reads and adds to `count`

Comment: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let counter = 0` only happens when you call `makeCounter()`. Each call to that returns a different closure, which has its own instance of the `count` variable.

Calling `counter()` doesn't call `makeCounter()` again, so it doesn't create a new `counter` variable. The closure remembers the instance of `count` that was created when you first called `makeClosure()`.

Comment: Thanks, I got confused thinking assignment copied the entire code from makeCounter. Which is not the case because we ran makeCounter() during assignment, so only the return value is given to counter() ... basically ```counter.count++``` or ```return count++;```